# Prevent portrait orientation of HTML5 game

Tags: android, ios, css, html

I want to run my HTML5 game only in landscape mode. If I rotate the device from landscape to portrait the appearance should remain in landscape orientation. This code:

```
 body[orient="portrait"] { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

has no effect in my canvas. If I use `media-screen orientation` the canvas and content is orienting but events inside game are not rotating to portrait.

How can I achieve my requirement?